# How do I call a method in C#? What is the correct place to call a method?

Tags: c#, methods, console

How do I call a method in C#? GetArea  & GetPerimeter are the methods that I need to call.

Here is my code that I am working on:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace MyRectangle

class Rectangle
{
    // Set private variables
    private int _height=0;
    private int _width=0;
    // Accessors
    public int Height{
        set { _height = 6; }
        get { return _height;}
    }
    public int Width {
        set { _width =8; }
        get { return _width;}
    }

    //Public

        public int GetArea()
            {
            return (_width * _height);
            }

            public int GetPerimeter()
            {
            return ((2 * _width) + (2 * _height));
            } 


}
Console.Write("Height is " + Height);
Console.Write("Width is " + Width);
Console.Write.GetArea() 
Console.Write.GetPerimeter() 

}
```

The console is where the output is displayed for debugging purposes.I am unsure where to call the methods.

Thank you!

Comment: Is nobody going to address his properties issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can call it from anywhere where it's legal to have any statements. But you seem to be missing a main function and incorrect method invocation syntax:

```
public static void Main() {
   Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();'
   rect.Height = 200;
   rect.Width = 100;

   Console.WriteLine("Height is " + rect.Height);
   Console.WriteLine("Width is " + rect.Width);
   Console.WriteLine(rect.GetArea());
   Console.WriteLine(rect.GetPerimeter());
}
```

Also, as Kevin points out, you need to have a `Rectangle` instance before you can do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of your `Rectangle` class using the `new` keyword. For console applications, this may be done in your `main()`.

This sounds like homework potentially. If so, I would recommend getting into the text book some. This is some of the basics of Object Oriented Programming.